# Keep subcategory grandson in slug

Tags: redirect, slug

I have the categories and subcategories father, son, grandson:

```
-father
--son
---grandson
```

When creating an post and mark it only in the grandson category, the correct slug is generated: `www.example.com/father/son/grandson/post-title`

If I mark the post in the son and grandson categories, the generated slug is `www.example.com/father/son/post-title`, excluding the grandson category from the url.

I would like the slug to have the category grandson.
Or at least do some redirect from `/father/son/post-title` to `/father/son/grandson/post-title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with WordPress — it does generate the proper permalink, be the post assigned to just `grandson` or `son` and `father`. It's just that for the latter, the "chosen" category could be either `son` or `father`, but not both — and if it's `son` (which has a parent category), then the permalink would have `/father/son/` and not just `/father/`.

#### But the structure you want, it is possible.

And it can be better achieved with manual intervention when editing the post, where you'd want to select a *primary category* for the post.

And I rarely suggest 3<sup>rd</sup> party plugins in my answers, but this time, I thought you should know there's a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-primary-category/) which can help you with that. Yoast SEO also comes with a similar feature, but not sure how/whether it works with permalinks..

Or if you want to do it programmatically/manually (without any fancy UI), then a simple approach would be:

1. Use the standard [custom fields editor](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) and add a field named `primary_category` with the category *slug* (e.g. `grandson` as in your example) as the field's value.
2. Use the [`post_link_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link_category/) hook to filter/set the category that WordPress uses when generating post permalinks having `%category%` in the structure: (this code would go in the theme functions file)

   ```php
   add_filter( 'post_link_category', function ( $cat, $cats, $post ) {
       if ( $post && ( $slug = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'primary_category', true ) ) ) {
           $term = get_category_by_slug( $slug );
           $cat = $term ? $term : $cat; // use $term if it's valid
       }
       return $cat;
   }, 10, 3 );
   ```

Note: The code is intended for the standard category taxonomy. You'll have to adjust it accordingly for custom taxonomies. :)

Comment: Great @Sally CJ. Thanks for pointing the way!